# My code is not getting fired

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myCarousel").bind(".slide", function (event) {
            var carousel = $(event.target);
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (carousel.find(".carousel-indicators .active").data("slide-to") === 2) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }, 0);
        });
});

            var safdfkl = $('#myCarousel .active').index('#myCarousel .item');
            var active = $('#myCarousel').find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
```

My need is that i want to get the active carousel value all the time infinite, where for example if the third slide is active i want to fire my code..
I am not able to find the current active slide itself please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using bootstrap. You need to update your binding,

For bootstrap 2,

```
 $("#myCarousel").bind("slide", function (event) {
```

For bootstrap 3,

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
```

Comment: After the document .ready function the Condition is not getting fired , it's getting outside of the loop why???

Comment: I am not pretty clear with "it's getting outside of the loop". Though, you can try to add console.log and check what is happening.

Comment: It's not getting inside means document.ready or the slide event? Additionally, slide event will not trigger on load but once you slide your carousel. It will be great, if you can replicate the problem and share either via fiddle, plunker or even email.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$("#myCarousel").bind("slide", function (event) {
    ...
}
```

Don't add dot to the event name.

**EDIT**

Try 'slid' event. Apparently slide happens before animation, slid happens after.

So use:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (event) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you...But when i refresh only the code is getting fired else not , what i want is that it should hit continuously so that every time when the carousel indicator class changes to active i need that data-slide-to number?????Please help brooooooooos....